# AJAX request not being rendered in js

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

I have a webpage which when it is loaded makes an ajax request to get some data in JSON [] format from the back end and display it on the page. The webpage is generated with MVC .NET

The function that loads the events from the back end:

```
function initEvents() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Work/GetEvents/' + id, type: "GET", dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            events = data;
        },
        error: function(data) {
            //  Note: hardcoded JSON event in here
            events = hardcodedEvents;
        },
        complete: function(data) {
            // Add events
            for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++){
                addEvent(events[i]);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

When I make the request fail (ie change the url to point to bogus data) - it goes in `error: function(data)` - so the hardcoded JSON object loads fine then it goes in the 'complete: function(data)` and adds the events 1 by 1.

However, when I use the correct URL and get the events from the backend, it seems the events arrive too late; just as it exits the `complete` section. The question is: Why is this happening? I thought `complete` loaded whenever the reply came back. Am I wrong to believe this? How can I fix this so the events are loaded from the back end and into the page?

Thanks!

Comment: Please, post the JSON response! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`events` is not defined in the scope of the `complete` event. You should pass the `events` data to another function, or simply move the `addEvent` logic to within the event handler. eg:

```
function onEventData(data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
        addEvent(data[i]);
    }
}

function initEvents() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Work/GetEvents/' + id, type: "GET", dataType: 'json',
        success: onEventData, 
        error: function(data) {
            //  Note: hardcoded JSON event in here
            onEventData(hardcodedEvents);
        }
    });
}
```

Note that `complete` is called when the request finishes (after success and error callbacks are executed). Since you only want to run your handler *once* per request, you shouldn't use it in this case.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a **scope** issue. Move your complete() code into a separate function and call it from both success() and error():

```
function renderEvents(data) {
    // Add events
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
        addEvent(data[i]);
    }
}

function initEvents() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Work/GetEvents/' + id, type: "GET", dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            renderEvents(data);
        },
        error: function(data) {
            //  Note: hardcoded JSON event in here
            renderEvents(hardcodedEvents);
        }
    });
}
```

EDIT: Fixed variable name in renderEvents().

Comment: I think you have the right idea, perhaps some syntax problem bc your version doesn't work Hamish' does. tx for the eye opener!

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot to rename "events" to "data". Updated answer. Oh well, glad it's working now!